# ServiceNow - query table and insert incident

Tags: javascript, while-loop, insert, servicenow

I m trying to implement a script that queries a table and checks for certain criteria.
If it is true then it will insert an incident.

I m not sure where this is going wrong, I am guessing it is the while loop.

I m new to scripting in `servicenow` if someone could assist.
Code is below

```
var kc = new GlideRecord('cmdb_ci_web_site');
   kc.addQuery('owned_by', '=', 
   current.u_caller_id.sys_id).addOrCondition('u_secondary_site_owner', '=', current.user.sys_id);
   kc.query();

   While (kc.next()) 
    {

          var inc = new GlideRecord('incident');
                  inc.initialize();
                  inc.short_description ='Assign New User to PSO or SSO';
                  inc.u_category = 'KCCC';
                  inc.current.u_caller_id.sys_id.setDisplayValue();
                  inc.to_be_encrypted ='Assign New User to PSO or SSO';
          inc.impact ='3';
          inc.urgency = '3';
                  inc.insert();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is suspicious `inc.current.u_caller_id.sys_id.setDisplayValue();` I would guess `inc.current` is undefined.

If that's still not working: I've had problems chaining the OR condition directly. Try setting a new variable for your OR condition:

```
    var kc = new GlideRecord('cmdb_ci_web_site');
    var kcOrCondition = kc.addQuery('owned_by', '=', current.u_caller_id.sys_id);
    kcOrCondition.addOrCondition('u_secondary_site_owner', '=', current.user.sys_id);
    kc.query();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure as to what you are trying to achieve with this line: `inc.current.u_caller_id.sys_id.setDisplayValue();`. Since caller_id is a reference field, you dont have to dot walk to it's sys_id to get the value, the system will automatically pick up the sys_id by default.

You can make changes to your script as:

```
var kc = new GlideRecord('cmdb_ci_web_site');
kc.addEncodedQuery('owned_by='+current.u_caller_id+'^OR u_secondary_site_owner='+current.user);
kc.query();
while (kc.next()) 
   {
       var inc = new GlideRecord('incident');
       inc.initialize();
       inc.setValue("short_description","Assign New User to PSO or SSO");
       inc.setValue("u_category", "KCCC");
       inc.setValue("to_be_encrypted", "Assign New User to PSO or SSO");
       //inc.setValue(relevant_incident_field, current.u_caller_id);
       inc.setValue("impact", "3");
       inc.setValue("urgency", "3");
       inc.insert();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this statement:
**inc.current.u_caller_id.sys_id.setDisplayValue();**

if you want to set a specific field in inc using the current value try this:
inc.somefieldininc = current.u_caller_id.sys_id;